# Kernel parameter to prioritize VGA over GPU output

Tags: boot, kernel

I have a Supermicro server with a display attached to the Nvidia GPU HDMI output, but I am working remotely with IPMI connection.  So I need to boot Ubuntu with the output going to VGA, or else the IPMI remote console is just black.  I figured out how to do this in grub, by setting `terminal_output vga_text` so now I see the grub menu on the IPMI console.  But as soon as it starts booting linux my screen goes black, and the output is shown only on the HDMI display.  Is there a kernel parameter to prioritize VGA over GPU output?  It works fine if I physically unplug the HDMI but that's not always practical with remote hands.

I've tried like this, which I expect to disable HDMI and force enable VGA but it doesn't work, I still get display out HDMI only.

```
$linux_cmd /live/vmlinuz boot=live console=ttyS1,115200n8 union=overlay username=user hostname=impish config quiet components noswap edd=on nomodeset enforcing=0 noeject locales= keyboard-layouts= ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch="no" video=VGA-1:800x600@60me video=HDMI-1:d toram=live,syslinux,EFI,boot,.disk,utils ip= net.ifnames=0  splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1
```